# Why Injecting Scope and RootScope to Controllers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

In Angular JS controllers, why do I have to inject both the scope and root scope, can't a controller have its scope as a child of the rootscope, and be injected by default, as in the view, I can always reference the attributes of both the scope and root scope as naked variables.......Why is this not for the controller too and even applied to the services as well?

Comment: One reason is that it makes unit testing both easy and *possible*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your thoughts are right about `$rootScope`. As per Angular Js documentation

[Every application has a single root scope. All other scopes are descendant scopes of the root scope. Scopes provide separation between the model and the view, via a mechanism for watching the model for changes. They also provide an event emission/broadcast and subscription facility.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

But reason of injecting is , thats how only Angular Works , injector functionality of Angular look for all injected dependency and create a reference of object. As per documentation also :

[A root scope can be retrieved using the $rootScope key from the $injector.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

Answer (score 1):

Actually , More users confused why both are used in controller

`$scope` is used for communicate between controller and view. $scope binds a view (DOM element) to the viewmodel

But rootscope, There is only one rootscope in the app and it is shared among all the components of an app. `$rootscope` a global variable. all others $scopes are children of that `$rootScope.`

**For Example**

there are two controllers both have scope

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 
 app.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.msg = 'World';
 $rootScope.name = 'AngularJS';
 });
 
 app.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.msg = 'Dot Net Tricks';
 $scope.myName = $rootScope.name;
 });
```

rootscope only availble for all controllers but scope didn't get from another controller

**Note**

> When you use ng-model with $rootScope objects then AngularJS updates
> those objects under a specific $scope of a controller but not at
> global level $rootScope. Create a private $scope for each controller
> to bind it to the view.

Comment: there would be two `$rootScope` in app..if there are two application bootstraped on same page..

Comment: it should be global using inject should be you get that one

Comment: you really need to go and read documentation please look at this plunkr and tell me how many rootscope are there http://plnkr.co/edit/rre9RD0tUbEcb0ty3bdw?p=preview

Comment: I appreciate, But I actually asked, why in this code would I still need to inject a controller's scope into itself......and more funny is that you inject it's parent.